# What is the best silicone sealer for a mobile home roof and best installation techniques?

Tags: waterproofing, roofing, silicone, metal-roof

Need some help here. We need to seal our single wide mobile home roof. I've read that silicone is best. From there I've seen multiple instalation recommendations from just clean the roof make sure its dry, make any repairs with fabric and silicone, then slap it on..... to clean and dry roof, thin coat, fabric, thin coat (all while wet) let dry then thick top coat.

So does anyone have any advice?

1. What silicone is best?
2. Is the thin coat/fabric/thin coat/top coat necessary? If not is it worth it to do?
3. What fabric needs to be used for repairs (if any) first? If not fabric, what is best to do repairs (cracks pin holes ect)?
4. Absolutely anything else you can think of that would guide/help us.

Comment: I have seen manufactured/ mobile homes with fiberglass shingle roofs and aluminium and other materials. What do you have? Silicone may not be the best choice depending on what roofing surface you are working with.   Give details about the roof. What material. What size of patch. Why is the patch needed...impact hole and damage,  Rot, just worn out roofing material.  Please give more details.

Comment: We have a metal roof, the seams were previously sealed with who knows what (before we moved in). Not knowing if it is silicone or not (nothing sticks to silicone except for silicone) we figured play it safe and use silicone.  We are planning on coating the entire roof to help it last longer. We have one small (pinhole) spot that has started leaking when it rains very hard. Other than that the roof is decent for its age. No wood rott was seen when we were redoing the ceilings (we completely gutted the trailer down to studs and started fresh).

Comment: Consider Polyurethane caulk.  Good for pin holes and sealing patches.  Stays pliable.  It's what i use on aluminium roofs.   I use Vulkem by Tremco...it sticks to silicone. Heck it sticks to anything.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the recommendation!